# Heroku not recognized as an internal or external command (Windows)

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloud, heroku-toolbelt

Following [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#deploy-the-app) heroku tutorial to launch an app on heroku. But when I use the command `heroku create`, it says it's not recognized. I added `C:\Program Files\Heroku` to my PATH. How do I fix this?

Comment: same sh*t here. I tried from git bash&cmd, windows cmd and node prompt...Any progress on your part?

Comment: I tried using $heroku it is not working. then I directly type heroku and it's working now.

Comment: Any updates? The proper directories are added to my PATH and I reopened my PowerShell window. Additionally, I restarted my computer but alas, it still does not recognize Heroku as a command.

Comment: For some reason my PATH was set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\heroku\bin` altough the correct path was `C:\Program Files\heroku\bin`. That fixed the problem

Comment: This problem usually occurs when you download the CLI, through whatever means, and don't refresh the command prompt you are using.

Answer (score 43):

You're probably using an old version or the deprecated package `'heroku-cli'`. The new one is just called 'heroku'
Uninstall that by

```
npm uninstall -g heroku-cli
```

Then install the new package

```
npm i -g heroku
```

And now all your works will go perfectly.Just try `heroku login` and any other `heroku` command.

Credit: https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/855#issuecomment-394758388

Comment: worked for me as well

Answer (score 27):

You can follow the [Getting Started on Heroku with Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction) .

My Heroku.exe PATH is in `C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin` .

Make sure your Heroku's Path is correct.

Or you can re-install the heroku.

Answer (score 16):

1.Set the Path in environment variables.

2.I created a separate path: Variable name : Heroku, Variable Path as 
   C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin.
   But it didn't work

3.so i added the same path in Path variable which is
   already created and it worked.

4.My Heroku.exe PATH is in C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin . 
   Make sure your Heroku's Path is correct. 
   Hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

I had this problem, after installing the heroku cli, i had to restart my *commend prompt* for a quick fix

Comment: great tip. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Just add `C:\Program Files\heroku\bin` to your `Environment Variables`.

[image]

Make sure to close and re-open the shell or cmd.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar problem. But closing old command prompt and opening new command prompt worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

In my case **Restarting** the IDE fixed.

Answer (score 5):

After installed heroku, just close the vs code. Reopen vs code, on the terminal type,

```
heroku --version
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation, This installation method is required for users on ARM and BSD. You must have node and npm installed already. So just install the package using npm.

```
 npm install -g heroku
```

Then in your terminal, type heroku --version will surely work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the same issue with Windows 10 Home.

- Open Windows Powershell
- type $env:PATH

Is your Heroku path actually there?
If not follow these steps:

- Open the Start Search, type in “env”, and choose “Edit the system
  environment variables”
- Click the “Environment Variables…” button

**Now check values for your Heroku inside both "User" and "System" "Path" variables.**

**Add your Heroku path where not listed.**
Works immediately with no any system restart.

Comment: You are supposed to use $env:PATH not $evn:PATH

Comment: Also in the case that the heroku path exists in path variables but still doesn't take effect immediately, you can restart the machine as it may work when you do.

Comment: this did it for me! I had Heroku in my User but not in my System Path

Answer (score 1):

Go to bin directory and run heroku application and then type "heroku login " for login or other commands

Really don't know why Powershell not identifying Heroku ,but the above hint will work.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue when I tried heroku command inside a command line window that was opened prior to installing the heroku CLI.

Simply running the command in a new command line window solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this it works for me
"C:\Program Files\heroku\bin\heroku.cmd" create

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue. I closed all existing command prompt/terminal and opening new command prompt, it did the work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download heroku CLI from [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)
2. Install it
3. Close all the terminal tabs and restart your IDE
   **Boom**

Answer (score 1):

It worked with git bash.

Run this command:

```
npm install -g heroku
```

on git bash, then try heroku login on bash.

Comment: I followed the other steps (involving environment variables), but those did not fix it for me. This one works and allows us to quickly upgrade the CLI!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone experiencing this error with `'C:\Program'` not recognized with `heroku pg:psql -c` then just do :

```
echo "yourcommand" | heroku pg:psql
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Heroku CLI through Scoop and you would be able to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Set the path in Environment variables.

> C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin

After setting path, still the same errors occurs.

**Restart the system and sometimes this happens. Try this also if setting path didn't work.**

Answer (score 0):

oh no worries u may have forgotten the path or haven't installed heroku yet

```
npm install -global heroku
```

or try deleting the previously depreciated package and reinstall it again

```
npm uninstall -global heroku-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing Heroku CLI works. If not, configure in environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Try going to My computer-> Properties -> advanced System Settings

In the advanced System Settings, go to

Environment variables

Path edit

new

`C:\Program Files\heroku\bin`

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Late arrival tip: if you have a separate administrator account (which you use to install new products), note that it probably added the path to your admin account but not your other account(s), which you actually intend to run it from. Add the path to the "system variables" section instead of the admin user section.

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked in PATH that C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin is set.
You need to close and reopen your terminal again

Answer (score 0):

There was another post here [Heroku won't load within Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900332/heroku-wont-load-within-visual-studio-code) I did that and it worked for me. After uninstalling and npm i -g heroku

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

install Heroku from official site.
close the terminal and open it again

type
heroku --version

Answer (score 0):

If your environment variable path is ok just refresh your terminal and it will work. I had the same issue and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

In my case closing and reopening VS code and terminal worked.

Answer (score -1):

Close the command prompt and open it again. That fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Just restart the the PC after setting the path.. It should work.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
$'curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh'
```

Answer (score -2):

For me I was not in the root folder   cd .. out of the proj