# 'heroku' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, django, heroku, host, heroku-ci

Actually I am trying to host my site live on Heroku and I downloaded Heroku cli also but when i am trying to run any Heroku command it didn't work. I have set environment variable also.
help me to find the solution.
I used Techstack as:
python, Django, sqlite3 and Heroku for hosting.
I am following this video and I am sharing link with you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBwhtEIXGII&list=PL-51WBLyFTg2vW-_6XBoUpE7vpmoR3ztO&index=23

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you install the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)? We're not going to watch a video to understand your question (and even if we did that only shows what the video says, not what you actually did). Please read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using an old version or the deprecated package '`heroku-cli`'. The new one is just called '`heroku`' Uninstall that by

```
npm uninstall -g heroku-cli
```

Then install the new package

```
npm i -g heroku
```

And now all your works will go perfectly.Just try `heroku` login and any other `heroku` command.
If still not works:
1.Set the Path in environment variables.

2.I created a separate path: Variable name : Heroku, Variable Path as C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin. But it didn't work

3.so i added the same path in Path variable which is already created and it worked.

4.My Heroku.exe PATH is in C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin . Make sure your Heroku's Path is correct.
[image]

Source:[Heroku not recognized as an internal or external command (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170691/heroku-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-windows)

Comment: it is solved but it is showing me update like below:
Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.59.0.
heroku/7.53.0 win32-x64 node-v12.21.0